# $Scope undefined when typescript property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, undefined

I am trying to use scope as a property of the controller, but when I use it in the program it thrown an exception that it is undefined. Is there a way to fix this, or a better way to use $Scope in a class?

```js
class PositionCtrl {

    $scope : ng.IScope;
    MyMap: google.maps.Map;
    //rectangles: Rectangle[];
    lat: number; long: number; rad: number;
    save() {
        alert("Settings Saved");
    }

    constructor() {            
        this.lat = 20;
        this.long = 20;
        this.rad = 10000;

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
        }
        this.MyMap = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.MyMap,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)),
            title: 'Some location'
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: this.MyMap,
            
            radius: Number(this.rad),
            fillColor: '#AA0000',
            clickable: false
        });
        
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');        

        //WATCH IS UNDEFINED
        this.$scope.$watch('Pos.rad', () => {
            circle.setRadius(Number(this.rad));
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
            console.log("done");
        });
        //WATCHGROUP IS UNDEFINED
        this.$scope.$watchGroup(['Pos.lat', 'Pos.long'],() => {
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(Number(this.lat), Number(this.long)));

            console.log("done");
        });
            
        //Click event
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.MyMap, 'click',(event) => {
            marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
            this.$scope.$apply(() => {
                this.lat = event.latLng.lat();
                this.long = event.latLng.lng();
            })
            var test: number = 0;
            console.log(this.lat);
            test = Number(this.rad);
            circle.setRadius(test);
            console.log(this.rad);
            console.log(circle.getRadius());
            circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
        });
    }
    event: google.maps.event;           
}

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller("PositionCtrl", ["$scope", PositionCtrl]);
```

Comment: Downvoted -- please post *minimal* examples. No one wants to read thirty lines of unrelated code and big chunks of empty lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has no way of knowing that you have a `$scope` member.

You need to add a constructor parameter for it:

```
 class MyClass {
    constructor(public $scope: ng.IScope) {
        // OK to use this.$scope here 
    }
 }
```

You can also use `$inject`:

```
class MyClass {
    // Parallel array to constructor arguments
    static $inject = ['$scope'];
    constructor(public myScope: ng.IScope) {
        myScope.$watch(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing before, but then I could not use $Scope in other class methods. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can use this.$scope in other methods when doing this.